# Mo refile targets

Tags: org-refile

I have the following setup:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-refile-targets
   '(("~/Documents/org/x.org, ~/Documents/org/y.org" :maxlevel . 5))))
```

I open `x.org` and position the cursor on a subtree, do `M-x org-refile-copy`, I get: "No refile targets". What could be the reason?

Comment: Did you see the answer? Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-h v org-refile-targets` says:

```
Targets for refiling entries with ‘M-x org-refile’.
This is a list of cons cells.  Each cell contains:
- a specification of the files to be considered, either a list of files,
  or a symbol whose function or variable value will be used to retrieve
  a file name or a list of file names.  If you use ‘org-agenda-files’ for
  that, all agenda files will be scanned for targets.  Nil means consider
  headings in the current buffer.
- ...
```

So the specification of the "files to be considered" is a list of files in this case. In Lisp, a list has the form `(a b c)` (see e.g. [List Processing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/List-Processing.html) in the Intro manual or [Cons Cell and List Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cons-Cell-Type.html) in the Elisp reference manual). In this case, you have two files (represented as strings), so a list of those files is

```
("~/Documents/org/x.org" "~/Documents/org/y.org)
```

Putting that into the `custom-set-variables` gives you:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-refile-targets
   '((("~/Documents/org/x.org" "~/Documents/org/y.org") :maxlevel . 5))))
```

N.B. No commas to separate the elements of the list. Each element is a string, so it has to be surrounded by double quotes - see [Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Lisp-Atoms.html) in the Elisp intro manual and [Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html) in the Elisp reference manual.